# how can an Angular component catch an event that happened before it was instantiated?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component that is not instantiated yet. It's inside a *ngIf so when the condition is set to true, it gets instantiated and appear on the page. I set the condition to true when I click on a button.
Inside that component, I have a hostlistener that listens on the click events.

So my question is, how comes the newly instantiated component can catch the click that happened before it was instantiated ?

here is a stackblitz to demonstrate the issue :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-click-lifecycle

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="showOtherComponent = true">Show other component</button>
  <hello *ngIf="showOtherComponent"></hello>
`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  showOtherComponent = false;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <span *ngIf="caughtClick">I caught the click even though I wasn't instanciated when it happened</span>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string = 'Other component';
  caughtClick = false;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Constructor');
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  handleClick(e) {
    console.log('Click handler is called but the click happened before the component was instanciated...');
   this.caughtClick = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you arrive at the conclusion `how comes the newly instantiated component can catch the click that happened before it was instantiated`?

Comment: btw, the listener is attached to `document`, not `component`. Changing hostListener to `@HostListener('click', ['$event'])` to see what happens.

Comment: @ABOS Changing to removing the 'document' before the click works for the first part. but then, after, the component can only listen to clicks inside itself, and not on the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that the rendering of your `<hello/>` component is happening in the same [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/) task as your button click. So, the order of events (in the same task) would be:

1. User clicks on "the show other component" `<button/>`
2. `showOtherComponent` of `<my-app/>` is changed to `true`
3. Angular leaves the `<my-app/>` click listener and begins to detect changes
4. Detects that the `<hello/>` component should be rendered so renders/instantiates it
5. Angular then sees the component has a listener for the document click, so runs it

**This is all happening in the original context of the document click** (if you look at the debug callstack, all the steps are still happening within the original click listener.). Because of this, your `<hello/>` component gets called. To work around this, you can simply change the `showOtherComponent` click listener to run on [another turn of the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="toggleComponent()">Show other component</button>
    <hello *ngIf="showOtherComponent"></hello>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  showOtherComponent = false;

  toggleComponent(){
    setTimeout(() => {//will run AFTER the click event is finished
       this.showOtherComponent = !this.showOtherComponent;
    });
  }

}
```

This ensures that the click listener that add's the `<hello/>` component is completely finished before it render's the component. [Here's the modified code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-click-lifecycle-zftfpy).